# why numpy place is not replacing empty strings

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, numpy

Hello i have an dataframe as shown below

```
daf = pd.DataFrame({'A':[10,np.nan,20,np.nan,30]})
daf['B'] = ''
```

the above code has created a data frame with  column B having empty strings

```
     A    B
0   10.0    
1   NaN 
2   20.0    
3   NaN 
4   30.0
```

the problem here is i need to replace column with all empty strings,(note here entire column should be empty)  with values provided with numpy place last argument here it is 1

so i used following code

`np.place(daf.to_numpy(),((daf[['A','B']] == '').all() & (daf[['A','B']] == '')).to_numpy(),[1])`

which did nothing it gave same output

```
    A    B
0   10.0    
1   NaN 
2   20.0    
3   NaN 
4   30.0
```

but when i assign `daf['B'] = np.nan` the code seems to work fine by checking  if entire column is null, then replace it with 1

here is the data frame

```
      A      B
0   10.0    NaN
1   NaN     NaN
2   20.0    NaN
3   NaN     NaN
4   30.0    NaN
```

replace where those nan with 1 where the entire column is nan

```
np.place(daf.to_numpy(),(daf[['A','B']].isnull() & daf[['A','B']].isnull().all()).to_numpy(),[1])
```

which gave correct output

```
    A        B
0   10.0    1.0
1   NaN     1.0
2   20.0    1.0
3   NaN     1.0
4   30.0    1.0
```

can some one tell me how to work with empty strings replacing , and give a reason why its not working with empty string as input

Comment: Maybe it has something to do with mixed `dtypes` in your original version of `daf`, compared to the same `dtype` in your updated version? The latter may mean the `to_numpy()` function returns a copy.

Answer (score 0):

If I'm understanding your question correctly, you're wanting to replace a column with empty strings with a column of 1s. This can be done with `pandas.replace()`

```
daf.replace('', 1.0)

      A    B
0  10.0  1.0
1   NaN  1.0
2  20.0  1.0
3   NaN  1.0
4  30.0  1.0
```

This function also works with regex if you want to be more granular with the replacement.

Comment: not only the empty string, the entire column should be empty string, we will not replace  empty strings that have data in their respective columns. so  corresponding specified column which are completely empty  need to be changed, for example may be there is a column C where entire data is empty string, there we dont need to change so we keeps empty strings as it is for that column C

Comment: So if you only want to place a 1 where column A is null then create a mask like `mask = daf.A.isna()` and then call `daf.loc[mask, 'B'] = 1.0`